# Imitate A 2 Column Magazine Page

Tags: css

This is not about a simple 2 column page layout.  Rather it's about how to create a bordered css box that would behave as if it were a 2 column magazine page, with content beginning by filling up the first column, and then only moving onto the second column when it ran out of space in the first column (either because more text was added, or because font-size increased).

A couple pictures of how the 2 column layout in MS Word works may help to clarify the issue.  Keep in mind the key point is that we do not know beforehand which content belongs in the first column and which in the second (that's an easy problem):

Content begins in column 1:

[image]

Content spills into column 2 when font-size is increased:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in css?

Comment: no, this would need javascript for sure.

Comment: @jackJoe: It does unfortunately need JavaScript if it must work in current versions of IE :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3 has the answer: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/bjfVe/

```
#container {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #666;

    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #666;

    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1em;
    column-rule: 1px solid #666;
}
```

The browser support is.. very predictable: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Comment: nice one, I didn't know that :) although it isn't interactive (depending on font-size changes), but it proves it can be done via CSS.